# how can i clear may table data if i click my reset button which resets my radio buttons on different forms

Tags: php, javascript

what i want is if i click my reset button, it resets my radio buttons and clears its value on may table data.... what should i add to my codes here...

```
function  clear(){
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('president') && document.getElementById('president');
    for(i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
        elems[i].checked=false;
    document.list.editform.president.value='';

}
```

lets say for instance the `document.getElementsByName('president')` is for my reset button which is on my editform and the `document.getElementById('president')` is for my table data which is on the other form. should it be possible that if i click the reset, two forms would be called on my function? plss help...

this is my select_candidate.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function  clear(){
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('president');
    for(i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
        elems[i].checked=false;
    document.list.editform.president.value='';

}
function get_president_value()
{
    for (var i=0; i < document.list.president.length; i++)
    {
        if (document.list.president[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementById('president').innerHTML = document.list.president[i].value;
        }
    }
}
-->
</script>
<form method="post" name="list">
    <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels" >
        <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
            <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">President</li>
        </ul>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"> 
        <fieldset>
            <legend>President</legend>
<?php require_once('candidate/president.php'); ?>   
        </fieldset></div>
</form>

<!-- here the value of my radio button will appear on this table data and this is where i want to clear as i click my reset button which clears also my radio buttons... -->
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>List of Your Candidates</legend>
        <table>
            <tr><td>President: </td> <td id="president" onclick="clear()"> </td> </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and heres my president.php

```
   <?php
   // get the records from the database
      if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidate_info WHERE position= 'president'"))
       {
        // display records if there are records to display
          if ($result->num_rows > 0)
         {
           // display records in a table
           echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>"; 
            // set table headers
         echo "<tr><th>Student ID</td><th>Course</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
             while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
               {
             // set up a row for each record
              echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->studid . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row->course . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->fname . " ". $row->mname ." ". $row->lname ." </td>";
   echo "<td><input type ='radio' name='president' id='". $row->studid ."' value='" . $row->fname . " ". $row->mname ." ". $row->lname ."' onchange='get_president_value()' ></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
            }
    echo "</table>";
           }
        // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
           else
            {
                echo "No results to display!";
          }
           }
            // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
                    else
                    {
            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
                    }
              // close database connection
                    $mysqli->close();
            //    <a href="records.php">Add New Record</a>      
            ?>
        //here is my reset button that resets my radio buttons
            <form name="editform" method="post">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" id="candidate2" onClick="clear()">
     </form></div>
```

Comment: Can we see your html please? There is probably a much more efficient method for this. I am thinking `getElementsByTagName`. Also, based on what you have provided so far - I have almost no idea what you are asking or how your page/html/js work in concert.

Comment: What are you trying to store in `elems`? Right now you're using the `&&` operator to set it to the return value of `document.getElementById('president')`, but only if `document.getElementsByName('president')` returns a truthy value.

Comment: @Jonathan..what i store on elems is the name of my reset button and the id of my table data but only the reset button is on the form 'editform'.

Comment: Can you create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @mrtsherman... also if you are confused, y is it on a tab, its because the program i am doing is on voting system. i just only put 1 sample but theres a lot of tabs on besides of president.

Comment: You are asking us how to clear radio buttons - but you posted no code that contains radio buttons. You might want to write down how your page looks, what its intent is, and what the user workflow will be. This will help you ask a clear question. Currently, what you are asking still makes no sense. Tabs, what tabs? You posted no code that showed tabs. Radio buttons? What radio buttons? You posted no code that contained radio buttons. Two forms? What are the two forms for? We are not mind readers...

Comment: Using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) will make this a lot easier than using bare bone javascript.

Comment: @mrtsherman i just updated my codes that i posted i included the radio buttons the workflow of my page is that as i click my radio buttons, it appears its value on my list which is on my table 'List of Candidates'. i do this for a purpose that i would only submit the list to save it on my database because this is the best way i though on gathering more data on my candidate lists. the tabs i mean is that if you observe my select_candidate.php it has a tab form where my president.php is called inside of it which is on the form named list then the other form is on the resetbutton on president.php

Comment: also my its intent is to cast a vote..

Answer (score 1):

```
Java Script Code use tableid.rows.length  take number of row;

        if(tabLen == 1){ return;}//its mean only header remaning no data 

        where rowId while creating table giving rowId string like "userRow" ;
        for (i=1; i< tabLen; i++)
                {
                    if (document.getElementById(rowId+(i-1)) != undefined)
                        tableToBeDeleted.deleteRow(document.getElementById(rowId+(i-1)).rowIndex);
                    else if (document.getElementById(rowId+"_New") != undefined)
                        tableToBeDeleted.deleteRow(document.getElementById(rowId+"_New").rowIndex);
                }
```